# Are there Move (_mm_move_ss) and Set (_mm_set_ss) intrinsics that work for doubles (__m128d)?

Tags: c++, x86, double, sse, intrinsics

Over the years,  a few times I have seen intrinsics functions with in `float` parameters that get transformed to `__m128` with the following code: `__m128 b = _mm_move_ss(m, _mm_set_ss(a));`.

For instance:

```
void MyFunction(float y)
{
    __m128 a = _mm_move_ss(m, _mm_set_ss(y)); //m is __m128
    //do whatever it is with 'a'
}
```

I wonder if there is a similar way of using `_mm_move` and `_mm_set` intrinsics to do the same for doubles (`__m128d`)?

Comment: What's `m`?  You know this is a merge, right?  It's not simply making a vector out of a `float`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yap, you are correct. I wrote the code sample by memory, but indeed it's `y` that is the function parameter. And `m` is a `__m128` vector that is declared and assigned outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every `_ss` and `_ps` intrinsic / instruction has a `double` version with a `_sd` or `_pd` suffix.  (Scalar Double or Packed Double).

For example, search [`(double` in Intel's intrinsic finder](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2&expand=3050,4590,3544&text=(double) to find intrinsic functions that take a `double` as the first arg.  Or just figure out what optimal asm would be, then look up the intrinsics for those instructions in the insn ref manual.  Except that it [doesn't list all the intrinsics for `movsd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html), so searching for an instruction name in the intrinsics finder often works.

re: header files: always just include `<immintrin.h>`.  It includes all Intel SSE/AVX intrinsics.

---

See also [ways to put a `float` into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766098/224132), and the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki for links about how to shuffle vectors.  (i.e. the tables of shuffle instructions in [Agner Fog's optimizing assembly guide](http://www.agner.org/optimize/))

(see below for a godbolt link to some interesting compiler output)

#### re: your sequence

Only use `_mm_move_ss` (or sd) if you actually want to merge two vectors.

You don't show how `m` is defined.  Your use of `a` as the variable name for the float and the vector imply that the only useful information in the vector is the `float` arg.  The variable-name clash of course means it doesn't compile.

There unfortunately doesn't seem to be any way to just "cast" a `float` or `double` into a vector with garbage in the upper 3 elements, like there is for `__m128` -> `__m256`:
[`__m256 _mm256_castps128_ps256 (__m128 a)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3050,4590,3544,577,577&text=castps128).  I posted a new question about this limitation with intrinsics: [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496/how-to-merge-a-scalar-into-a-vector-without-the-compiler-wasting-an-instruction)

I tried using `_mm_undefined_ps()` to achieve this, hoping this would clue in the compiler that it can just leave the incoming high garbage in place, in

```
// don't use this, it doesn't make better code
__m128d double_to_vec_highgarbage(double x) {
  __m128d undef = _mm_undefined_pd();
  __m128d x_zeroupper = _mm_set_sd(x);
  return _mm_move_sd(undef, x_zeroupper);
}
```

but clang3.8 compiles it to

```
    # clang3.8 -O3 -march=core2
    movq    xmm0, xmm0              # xmm0 = xmm0[0],zero
    ret
```

So no advantage, still zeroing the upper half instead of compiling it to just a `ret`.  gcc actually makes pretty bad code:

```
double_to_vec_highgarbage:  # gcc5.3 -march=nehalem
    movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp-16], xmm0      # %sfp, x
    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp-16]      # D.26885, %sfp
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0      # __Y
    movsd   xmm0, xmm1    # tmp93, D.26885
    ret
```

---

`_mm_set_sd` appears to be the best way to turn a scalar into a vector.

```
__m128d double_to_vec(double x) {
  return _mm_set_sd(x);
}
```

clang compiles it to a `movq xmm0,xmm0`, gcc to a store/reload with `-march=generic`.

---

Other interesting compiler outputs [from the `float` and `double` versions on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dnehalem',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQZA%2BpegIwBMAHEgGZQD2Ahtpdu5QDcEEABRsu2JAA8AlEgDeZJElwJsMXGCQ10lAM5r9ekbIDcZAL4VqdJqw7de/IREpEQAcyIfOuAEacHghiDpKyCkraNAzMMGCILEgAvNqYlHEJ4AhwlAAOxjLmyjYx0pQAXgi47DC5uVXJqboGPHrGZpGq6ppNNOxCRiIZCCwANGWV1bX1uIWWFFTRduKOfILClA5wIRLScorKXRpaOptcOW0iAGQdVou2zACyAJ4AYnEQ2CDsYDvcSM8ZGQDsoog8kOhGqcWpN%2BPkRHNQWDSpwoWl0P0EIN0ONoYZLoDESo1MckJwiqCAPSUuDsJAAdyI3AQQlwSBAkhAegZHKISAA5Jx%2BfMyNSxeKJcpaTA/FBkKy9N8wAAuYm5KCcCDINqU/I87B8vRwXVwUWUpB6djoZBwEAsFhVBCQBB6VVmpDQThgDxIAC06F8ECISSCYCqIAgFqtagwLqQMAM3NUHl9yYh/QAjkg%2BEhYdmiMhpg0mVAWO7GY72ZJbXAwPzJAnkBiBHBWOw2QbtZxrUhchpcuwDOytJ37LsFUrrEtGK3pbKsWsXCI53K9hFDiSenjWttblOHrOavOnOtXO4vD5/IFgivkOEQSUmK3hokUqcX1kcrltkTHzOJlUNR1A0b5pC0%2Bi7kSRxbuimIQUM8QjOMUgVIBRazOYdz3DEh4ynKJ4uGcnDbLea4gtBJxpFs8E3HMdx/rhx4vO8kBfD8y5HqugLrqCDEQmizRqLCeQ/hSxTTq2qKgbozZYkaIg4r04HyYSFIUWSYlINStIMky2Asg0HLsty9K8gKQqWEAAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
float_to_vec:   # gcc 5.3 -O3 -march=core2
    movd    eax, xmm0       # x, x
    movd    xmm0, eax       # D.26867, x
    ret

float_to_vec:   # gcc5.3 -O3 -march=nehalem
    insertps        xmm0, xmm0, 0xe # D.26867, x
    ret

double_to_vec:    # gcc5.3 -O3 -march=nehalem.  It could still have use movq or insertps, instead of this longer-latency store-forwarding round trip
    movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp-16], xmm0      # %sfp, x
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp-16]      # D.26881, %sfp
    ret
```

```
float_to_vec:   # clang3.8 -O3 -march=core2 or generic (no -march)
    xorps   xmm1, xmm1
    movss   xmm1, xmm0              # xmm1 = xmm0[0],xmm1[1,2,3]
    movaps  xmm0, xmm1
    ret

double_to_vec:  # clang3.8 -O3 -march=core2, nehalem, or generic (no -march)
    movq    xmm0, xmm0              # xmm0 = xmm0[0],zero
    ret


float_to_vec:    # clang3.8 -O3 -march=nehalem
    xorps   xmm1, xmm1
    blendps xmm0, xmm1, 14          # xmm0 = xmm0[0],xmm1[1,2,3]
    ret
```

**So both clang and gcc use different strategies for `float` vs. `double`, even when they could use the same strategy.**

Using integer operations like `movq` between floating-point operations causes extra bypass delay latency.  Using `insertps` to zero the upper elements of the input register should be the best strategy for float or double, so all compilers *should* use that when SSE4.1 is available.  xorps + blend is good, too, and can run on more ports than insertps.  The store/reload is probably the worst, unless we're bottlenecked on ALU throughput, and latency doesn't matter.

Comment: Superb answer, thanks! It not only answered my simple question, but quite honestly already answered a few other doubts I had in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

`_mm_move_sd`, `_mm_set_sd`. They're SSE2 intrinsics (and not SSE), so you'll need `#include <emmintrin.h>`.

Comment: You can always just `#include <immintrin.h>`.  No need to mess with all the legacy names for header files for different extensions.