# What are the costs of failed store-to-load forwarding on x86?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, amd-processor

What are the costs of a failed store-to-load forwarding on recent x86 architectures?

In particular, store-to-load forwarding that fails because the load partly overlaps an earlier store, or because the earlier load or store cross some alignment boundary that causes the forwarding to fail.

Certainly there is a latency cost: how big is it? Is there also a throughput cost, e.g., does a failed store-to-load forwarding use additional resources that are then unavailable to other loads and stores, or even other non-memory operations?

Is there a difference when all the parts of the store come from the store buffer, versus the case where it's a mix of the store buffer and L1?

Comment: Yeah, I've wondered this, too.  Did you ever get around to testing it?  There's some evidence an SF stall can't pipeline with other SF stalls on Intel IvB (https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/03/09/Store-forwarding#one-more-interesting-experiment using your own uarch-bench), but I don't know if successful store-forwarding is possible during this.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I don't think I did.

Answer (score 6):

It is not really a full answer, but still evidence that the penalty is visible.

MSVC 2022 benchmark, compiler with `/std:c++latest`.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

struct alignas(16) S
{
    char* a;
    int* b;
};

extern "C" void init_fused_copy_unfused(int n, S & s2, S & s1);
extern "C" void init_fused_copy_fused(int n, S & s2, S & s1);
extern "C" void init_unfused_copy_unfused(int n, S & s2, S & s1);
extern "C" void init_unfused_copy_fused(int n, S & s2, S & s1);

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    S s1, s2;
    constexpr int N = 1'000'000'000;
    auto t1 = system_clock::now();
    init_fused_copy_fused(N, s2, s1);
    auto t2 = system_clock::now();
    init_fused_copy_unfused(N, s2, s1);
    auto t3 = system_clock::now();
    init_unfused_copy_fused(N, s2, s1);
    auto t4 = system_clock::now();
    init_unfused_copy_unfused(N, s2, s1);
    auto t5 = system_clock::now();

    std::cout
     << "init fused copy fused     " << duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1) << "\n"
     << "init fused copy unfused   " << duration_cast<duration<double>>(t3 - t2) << "\n"
     << "init unfused copy fused   " << duration_cast<duration<double>>(t4 - t3) << "\n"
     << "init unfused copy unfused " << duration_cast<duration<double>>(t5 - t4) << "\n";
}
```

```
.code

c     db 0
i     dd 0

s     dq byte ptr [c], dword ptr [i]

ALIGN 16
init_fused_copy_fused PROC
    movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [s]
    movups      xmmword ptr [r8],xmm0

    movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [r8]
    movups      xmmword ptr [rdx], xmm1

    dec ecx
    jnz init_fused_copy_fused
    ret
init_fused_copy_fused ENDP


ALIGN 16
init_unfused_copy_fused PROC

    lea         rax, byte ptr [c]
    mov         qword ptr[r8], rax
    lea         rax, dword ptr [i]
    mov         qword ptr[r8 + 8], rax

    movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [r8]
    movups      xmmword ptr [rdx], xmm1

    dec ecx
    jnz init_unfused_copy_fused
    ret
init_unfused_copy_fused ENDP

ALIGN 16
init_fused_copy_unfused PROC
    movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [s]
    movups      xmmword ptr [r8],xmm0

    mov         rax, qword ptr[r8]
    mov         qword ptr[rdx], rax
    mov         rax, qword ptr[r8 + 8]
    mov         qword ptr[rdx +8], rax

    dec ecx
    jnz init_fused_copy_unfused
    ret
init_fused_copy_unfused ENDP


ALIGN 16
init_unfused_copy_unfused PROC

    lea         rax, byte ptr [c]
    mov         qword ptr[r8], rax
    lea         rax, dword ptr [i]
    mov         qword ptr[r8 + 8], rax

    mov         rax, qword ptr[r8]
    mov         qword ptr[rdx], rax
    mov         rax, qword ptr[r8 + 8]
    mov         qword ptr[rdx +8], rax

    dec ecx
    jnz init_unfused_copy_unfused
    ret
init_unfused_copy_unfused ENDP

END
```

```
init fused copy fused     0.664739s
init fused copy unfused   0.935631s
init unfused copy fused   4.34326s
init unfused copy unfused 1.02741s
```

CPU: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.21 GHz`

I interpret the results as follows:

- With fused init, the forwarding never fails. The difference between fused and unfused copy is within the benchmark error
- With unfused init, the fused copy caused forwarding failure, causing a significant performance difference

Comment: Seems to confirm that SF stalls can't pipeline with other SF stalls, like https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/03/09/Store-forwarding#one-more-interesting-experiment found for IvyBridge.  (Or at least limited ability; not sure if a 3.5x throughput penalty is all we'd expect, although call/ret overhead from using C++ instead of asm may be hiding some of the potential throughput of fused init and copy.  e.g. extra push of return address by `call`, and pop by `ret`, and also maybe loading a func pointer and other locals from memory in the caller.)

Comment: Keep in mind that if the store buffer has time to drain before the copy, there's no penalty to do a wide load from L1d cache.  So in practice you only get a penalty if something inits memory, and then something else very soon reads it from code that didn't manage to inline into the same function and optimize away the store/reload.

Comment: The bigger problem that I want to optimize is `std::move_only_function` ([PR](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/2267/files)). It is polymorphic, like `std::function`, so it contains pointer to implementation similar to vtable ptr, and the target pointer for large functor or the target data for small functor (which is often enough pointer sized trivially-copyable). So the move constructor implementation is called by a pointer, and often it just copies two pointers. I'll consider special-casing this case to avoid call by pointer, despite a conditional branch and more code at call site.

Comment: @PeterCordes, fixed a mistake in benchmark, forgot to prevent inlining of init. the results is more odd now. Will probably have to try assembly benchmark without `call`/`ret`

Comment: Why is inlining of one of the two functions a problem?  Did that mean even "unfused" init optimized into a single wide store or got hoisted?  It's highly suspicious that init&copy fused came out slower than init&copy unfused.  I don't think SF *latency* should be coming into those, at least not [the variable-latency effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189685/adding-a-redundant-assignment-speeds-up-code-when-compiled-without-optimization) where reloading after 3 cycles can succeed then, but reloading sooner means it costs 5c latency on SnB-family CPUs including yours.

Comment: Maybe related? [Understanding micro-architectural causes for longer code to execute 4x faster (AMD Zen 2 architecture)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66438609) found while looking for something else.  Also [Why does this function run so much faster when it makes an extra read of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65756336) is another one about variable-latency store forwarding, with a test loop that demos it cleanly with NOPs for a delay.

Comment: @PeterCordes, edited again to change code to real asm and avoid `call`/`ret`, now results should make sense, and the failed forwarding penalty is even more noticeable

Answer (score 4):

On the Intel [Sandy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge) family, store-forwarding stalls can't pipeline with other store-forwarding stalls.  Even on independent addresses, they conflict for throughput. See *[Store forwarding by example, One more interesting experiment](https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/03/09/Store-forwarding#one-more-interesting-experiment)* for [Ivy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_%28microarchitecture%29), and [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135369/what-are-the-costs-of-failed-store-to-load-forwarding-on-x86/69536321#69536321) for [Coffee Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_Lake) ([Skylake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)) derivative).

But a failed (slow-path) store-forwarding doesn't seem to block *successful* store-forwarding.  Testing on Skylake (i7-6700k) I made a test loop that includes two dependency chains:

- store / wider-reload causing a store-forwarding failure.  With that alone, 15 cycles per iteration on that latency bottleneck.
- 3x normal store/reload: ~13.425 cycles per iteration with just that.
- with both dependency chains in parallel: 15 or 16 cycles per iteration, depending on placement of things.

```
;; nasm -felf64 testloop.asm
;; ld -o testloop testloop.o
;; taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock:u,context-switches:u,cpu-migrations:u,page-faults:u,cycles:u,branches:u,instructions:u,uops_issued.any:u,uops_executed.thread:u,idq.dsb_uops:u -r1 ./testloop

default rel
%ifdef __YASM_VER__
    CPU Conroe AMD
    CPU Skylake AMD
%else
%use smartalign
alignmode p6, 64
%endif

global _start
_start:

    lea        rdi, [buf]
    mov     ebp, 100000000

align 64
.loop:
    mov [rdi+64], ecx
;    mov  rcx, [rdi+64]   ; reload here: 16c.  Or 16.8 if we *also* reload after the %rep block
%rep 3
    mov [rdi], eax
    mov eax, [rdi]
%endrep
    mov  rcx, [rdi+64]     ; reload here: 15c
    dec ebp
    jnz .loop
.end:

;;NASM-only, not YASM:   %if __BITS__ == 32
%ifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elf32
    mov eax,1
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 0x80     ; sys_exit(0) 32-bit ABI
%else
    xor edi,edi
    mov eax,231   ; __NR_exit_group  from /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h
    syscall       ; sys_exit_group(0)
%endif

section .bss
align 4096
buf:    resb 4096
```

Performance results:

```
$ t=testloop; asm-link -dn "$t".asm && taskset -c 3 perf stat --all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,ld_blocks.store_forward,resource_stalls.sb -r2 ./"$t"
+ nasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels testloop.asm
+ ld -o testloop testloop.o

testloop:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:       48 8d 3d f9 0f 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xff9]        # 402000 <__bss_start>
  401007:       bd 00 e1 f5 05          mov    ebp,0x5f5e100
  40100c:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  401014:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  40101c:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  401024:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  40102c:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  401034:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  40103c:       0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000401040 <_start.loop>:
  401040:       89 4f 40                mov    DWORD PTR [rdi+0x40],ecx
  401043:       89 07                   mov    DWORD PTR [rdi],eax
  401045:       8b 07                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi]
  401047:       89 07                   mov    DWORD PTR [rdi],eax
  401049:       8b 07                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi]
  40104b:       89 07                   mov    DWORD PTR [rdi],eax
  40104d:       8b 07                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rdi]
  40104f:       48 8b 4f 40             mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rdi+0x40]
  401053:       ff cd                   dec    ebp
  401055:       75 e9                   jne    401040 <_start.loop>

0000000000401057 <_start.end>:
  401057:       31 ff                   xor    edi,edi
  401059:       b8 e7 00 00 00          mov    eax,0xe7
  40105e:       0f 05                   syscall

Performance counter stats for './testloop' (two runs):

            385.85 msec task-clock                #    0.999 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.02% )
                 0      context-switches          #    0.000 /sec
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 /sec
                 2      page-faults               #    5.183 /sec
     1,503,701,305      cycles                    #    3.897 GHz                      ( +-  0.01% )
     1,000,000,130      instructions              #    0.67  instructions per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
       900,084,383      uops_issued.any           #    2.333 G/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
     1,300,091,135      uops_executed.thread      #    3.369 G/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
        99,933,928      ld_blocks.store_forward   #  258.998 M/sec                    ( +-  0.02% )
       443,686,304      resource_stalls.sb        #    1.150 G/sec                    ( +-  4.87% )

          0.386139 +- 0.000119 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  0.03% )
```