# Is there a way to shuffle a 8bitX32 ymm register right/left by N positions (c++)

Tags: c++, simd, clang++, avx2

Pretty much what the title says, i need a way to shift/shuffle the positions of all elements in a 256-avx-register register by N places. all i have found about this uses 32 or 64 bit values (__builtin_ia32_permvarsf256) etc. Help would be much appreciated.

`Example: {2,4,4,2,4,5,0,0,0,0,...} shift right by 4 -> {0,0,0,0,2,4,4,2,4,5,...}`

Comment: You need [`VPSHUFB` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb) (or corresponding intrinsic for C++, `_mm256_shuffle_epi8`).

Comment: If N is constant, you may also look at `_mm256_bslli_epi128`/`_mm256_bsrli_epi128` and `_mm256_permute2x128_si256`+`_mm256_or_si256` to combine the shifted lanes.

Comment: Not easily (not with a single shuffle until AVX-512 or if N is a multiple of 4), often it's easier to reload from memory and let the load execution unit handle misalignment, if the data you want is still in memory.

Comment: thanks for all your answers, ill take a look at ```_mm256_shuffle_epi8```. N cannot be constant. wich is one of the reasons im having so much trouble with this, all other solutions ive found thus far requires N to be a constant. (Peter Cordes) do you mean i should smack the register elements into a pointer, shuffle it, and then load it back in? it would be a possible solution, but id rather avoid doing it like that

Comment: @lunave: (make sure you @ someone you're replying to so they get notified).  No, I meant if your original vector had just been loaded from memory, consider doing another overlapping load from a different offset.  If not, storing and then reloading is not nearly as nice, costing more front-end uops for throughput.  (And for latency, a store-forwarding stall.)  Although it actually is worth considering for non-constant byte-shift counts; it's a latency vs. throughput tradeoff where the best choice depends on the surrounding code.

Answer (score 3):

If the shift distance is known at compile time, it’s relatively easy and quite fast. The only caveat, 32-byte byte shift instructions do that independently for 16-byte lanes, for shifts by less than 16 bytes need to propagate these few bytes across lanes. Here’s for the left shift:

```
// Move 16-byte vector to higher half of the output, and zero out the lower half
inline __m256i setHigh( __m128i v16 )
{
    const __m256i v = _mm256_castsi128_si256( v16 );
    return _mm256_permute2x128_si256( v, v, 8 );
}

template<int i>
inline __m256i shiftLeftBytes( __m256i src )
{
    static_assert( i >= 0 && i < 32 );
    if constexpr( i == 0 )
        return src;
    if constexpr( i == 16 )
        return setHigh( _mm256_castsi256_si128( src ) );
    if constexpr( 0 == ( i % 8 ) )
    {
        // Shifting by multiples of 8 bytes is faster with shuffle + blend
        constexpr int lanes64 = i / 8;
        constexpr int shuffleIndices = ( _MM_SHUFFLE( 3, 2, 1, 0 ) << ( lanes64 * 2 ) ) & 0xFF;
        src = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64( src, shuffleIndices );
        constexpr int blendMask = ( 0xFF << ( lanes64 * 2 ) ) & 0xFF;
        return _mm256_blend_epi32( _mm256_setzero_si256(), src, blendMask );
    }
    if constexpr( i > 16 )
    {
        // Shifting by more than half of the register
        // Shift low half by ( i - 16 ) bytes to the left, and place into the higher half of the result.
        __m128i low = _mm256_castsi256_si128( src );
        low = _mm_slli_si128( low, i - 16 );
        return setHigh( low );
    }
    else
    {
        // Shifting by less than half of the register, using vpalignr to shift.
        __m256i low = setHigh( _mm256_castsi256_si128( src ) );
        return _mm256_alignr_epi8( src, low, 16 - i );
    }
}
```

However, if the shift distance is not known at compile time, this is rather tricky. Here’s one method. It uses quite a few shuffles, but I hope it’s still somewhat faster than the obvious way with two 32-byte stores (one of them is to write zeroes) followed by 32-byte load.

```
// 16 bytes of 0xFF (which makes `vpshufb` output zeros), followed by 16 bytes of identity shuffle [ 0 .. 15 ], followed by another 16 bytes of 0xFF
// That data allows to shift 16-byte vectors by runtime-variable count of bytes in [ -16 .. +16 ] range
inline std::array<uint8_t, 48> makeShuffleConstants()
{
    std::array<uint8_t, 48> res;
    std::fill_n( res.begin(), 16, 0xFF );
    for( uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
        res[ (size_t)16 + i ] = i;
    std::fill_n( res.begin() + 32, 16, 0xFF );
    return res;
}
// Align by 64 bytes so the complete array stays within cache line
static const alignas( 64 ) std::array<uint8_t, 48> shuffleConstants = makeShuffleConstants();

// Load shuffle constant with offset in bytes. Counterintuitively, positive offset shifts output of to the right.
inline __m128i loadShuffleConstant( int offset )
{
    assert( offset >= -16 && offset <= 16 );
    return _mm_loadu_si128( ( const __m128i * )( shuffleConstants.data() + 16 + offset ) );
}

// Move 16-byte vector to higher half of the output, and zero out the lower half
inline __m256i setHigh( __m128i v16 )
{
    const __m256i v = _mm256_castsi128_si256( v16 );
    return _mm256_permute2x128_si256( v, v, 8 );
}

inline __m256i shiftLeftBytes( __m256i src, int i )
{
    assert( i >= 0 && i < 32 );
    if( i >= 16 )
    {
        // Shifting by more than half of the register
        // Shift low half by ( i - 16 ) bytes to the left, and place into the higher half of the result.
        __m128i low = _mm256_castsi256_si128( src );
        low = _mm_shuffle_epi8( low, loadShuffleConstant( 16 - i ) );
        return setHigh( low );
    }
    else
    {
        // Shifting by less than half of the register
        // Just like _mm256_slli_si256, _mm_shuffle_epi8 can't move data across 16-byte lanes, need to propagate shifted bytes manually.
        __m128i low = _mm256_castsi256_si128( src );
        low = _mm_shuffle_epi8( low, loadShuffleConstant( 16 - i ) );
        const __m256i cv = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256( loadShuffleConstant( -i ) );
        const __m256i high = setHigh( low );
        src = _mm256_shuffle_epi8( src, cv );
        return _mm256_or_si256( high, src );
    }
}
```

Comment: The second method was what i needed! thanks.. altough it looks very complicated

Comment: *somewhat faster than [two stores + reload]* - yes for latency, not necessarily for throughput.  A store-forwarding stall costs something like 10c latency, but if OoO exec can hide it then it might not cost much throughput.  (It's not truly a "stall" in the sense of stopping other stuff from running in parallel.)

Comment: Note that [`vperm2i128`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vperm2i128) (_mm256_permute2x128_si256) can zero either lane using bit 3 or 7 of the immediate, so you can use that for the constant `i >= 16` case, along with a 256-bit `vplldq`.  Should be better on all CPUs except Zen1 than the `vpslldq xmm` / `vpxor zero` / `vinsertf128` you might expect.  For the non-constant case, I guess you can broadcast-load the `vpshufb` control vector so the shuffle happens in the upper lane.  (Hopefully `_mm256_set1_si128( loadShuffleConstant( 16 - i ) )` compiles to VBROADCASTI128)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good ideas, updated. There’s no `_mm256_set1_si128` in my Visual C++, but I’ve confirmed `_mm256_broadcastsi128_si256` does the right thing in release builds, which is `vbroadcasti128 ymm1,oword ptr [r8]`

Comment: Just had another idea about this: for the constant `i` case, instead of `<<` / `>>` / OR, use `vperm2i128` to set up for `vpalignr`.  The latter has highly-inconvenient behaviour of shifting in bytes from the corresponding lane, but `vperm2i128` to lane-swap and zero creates a vector with the right data to shift in for each lane (zeros into the low lane,  low lane into the high lane).

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, appears to work. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes could you also show the "obvius" way with two 32-byte stores (one of them is to write zeroes) followed by 32-byte load? im not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @Iunave See there: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/7d1ce74a8bbfbe75d20ff0b935c1660f

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late, but this code is much simpler.

```
int8_t ShiftBox[96] = { 0 };
int8_t* WorkArea = &ShiftBox[32];

int8_t TestOriginal[32] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32};
int8_t TestResult[32];

// 0 <= N <= 32
void ShiftR(int8_t* InA, int8_t* OutA, int8_t N) {
    _mm256_storeu_epi8(WorkArea, _mm256_loadu_epi8(InA));
    _mm256_storeu_epi8(OutA, _mm256_loadu_epi8(WorkArea - N*sizeof(int8_t)));
}

in programm ShiftR(TestOriginal, TestResult, 6); // >>6
```

Comment: This costs a store-forwarding stall, but yes, that's worth considering if latency doesn't matter, just front-end throughput and back-end execution ports.  ([What are the costs of failed store-to-load forwarding on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69631247) - SF failures can't pipeline with other SF failures, so it's also not good if you need multiple vector-shifts in sequence.)

Comment: Also, you need to store the zeros before/after each time, otherwise there will be garbage from a previous call.  And you should make the buffer a local variable since you can't avoid at least one other store of zeros (maybe skipping one depending on sign of the count).  A local buffer also makes it thread-safe, which this isn't!

Comment: Normally you'd define it as `__m256i ShiftR(__m256i v, int N)`.  With `int8_t*` args, you'd have to pass it pointers to `__m256i` variables, making it harder for the compiler to optimize and keep them in registers.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Cordes: I converted the previous solution into this option. The compiler generates almost the same code that I would write manually in assembly language. Buffer `ShiftBox` is declared and initialized globally for each program thread (if multiple threads are used) since it does not accumulate garbage when a procedure is called. If you declare it locally, the compiler generates a lot of code to create the stack and fill it with zeros. Regarding the write-read delays, you can check the code using a benchmark, but I think they will be small since a maximum of 32 shifts are needed for `int8_t (uint8_t)` to make the vector zero.

```
__m256i ShiftBox[3] = { 0 };

__m256i TestOriginal_i8 = { .m256i_i8 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32} };
__m256i TestOriginal_i32 = { .m256i_i32 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} };

__m256i TestResult;

// right shift by N positions of a vector __m256i represented as an array of elements of type T
template <typename T> __m256i ShiftRight(__m256i Src, size_t N) {
    __m256i tmp;
    _mm256_storeu_si256(&ShiftBox[1], _mm256_loadu_si256(&Src));
    if (N > (sizeof(__m256i) / sizeof(T))) _mm256_storeu_si256(&tmp, _mm256_loadu_si256(&ShiftBox[0]));
    else {
        size_t load_address = (size_t)&ShiftBox[1];
        load_address -= N * sizeof(T);
        _mm256_storeu_si256(&tmp, _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(load_address)));
    }
    return tmp;
}
in programm:
    size_t NN;
    std::cout << "NN = "; std::cin >> NN;
    TestResult = ShiftRight<int8_t>(TestOriginal_i8, NN); // ShiftR<int8_t>(TestOriginal_i32, NN) Ok
    TestResult = ShiftRight<int32_t>(TestOriginal_i32, NN); // ShiftR<int32_t>(TestOriginal_i8, NN) Ok
```

Comment: This seems to be cross-posted as [Quickest way to shift/rotate byte vector with SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77715146) which includes a rotate version.  My comment there applies here, too.  You declared it global, not thread-local, so IDK what you mean about it being declared "for each program thread".  You'd have to change the code to make that happen, and TLS increases overhead to access it.  If you need this function in a loop, stack space only has to get reserved once, and it should only take 2 instructions to store a `0` and the vector.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about with *I think they will be small since a maximum of 32 shifts are needed for int8_t (uint8_t) to make the vector zero*.  For any given shift, you store the vector and do a load.  If you have lots of different vectors of data, each one is a separate shift, which you'd hope could run in parallel if the data was independent.  But that can't happen here.  If you need lots of different shifts of the *same* data, that's idea, yeah, store once and reload many times at different offsets.  You wouldn't want to do a chain of store / reload / store / reload with count=1.