# How to move eight __mmask64 to one __m512i "bitwise transposed"

Tags: c++, simd, avx, avx2, avx512

I'm currently working on an image processing routine dealing with high resolution 8bit images.
After computing eight `__mmask64` I need to pack them to one `__m512i` **bitwise transposed** for further processing, and I came up with following solution:

```
const __m512i c_128 = _mm512_set1_epi8(128);
const __m512i c_64 = _mm512_set1_epi8(64);
const __m512i c_32 = _mm512_set1_epi8(32);
const __m512i c_16 = _mm512_set1_epi8(16);
const __m512i c_8 = _mm512_set1_epi8(8);
const __m512i c_4 = _mm512_set1_epi8(4);
const __m512i c_2 = _mm512_set1_epi8(2);
const __m512i c_1 = _mm512_set1_epi8(1);
__mmask64 m128, m64, m32, m16, m8, m4, m2, m1;
__m512i vector;

// .
// generate mask
// .
// .
// .

vector = _mm512_maskz_mov_epi8(m128, c_128);
vector = _mm512_mask_add_epi8(vector, m64, vector, c_64);
vector = _mm512_mask_add_epi8(vector, m32, vector, c_32);
vector = _mm512_mask_add_epi8(vector, m16, vector, c_16);
vector = _mm512_mask_add_epi8(vector, m8, vector, c_8);
vector = _mm512_mask_add_epi8(vector, m4, vector, c_4);
vector = _mm512_mask_add_epi8(vector, m2, vector, c_2);
vector = _mm512_mask_add_epi8(vector, m1, vector, c_1);
```

And I don't like it even though it works:

- eight zmm registers are occupied by dull constants
- eight instructions for creating a single vector are too many
- chain of dependency

I've been looking for instructions/intrinsics that could do that above more elegantly, but `AVX512` simply has so many subsets with hundreds of instructions total.

Could someone give me some hints on this? Even just naming some instructions/instructions would help me tremendeously. - Or - Did I already find the best solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which AVX512 subsets are available? Do you have GFNI?

Comment: @harold Yes, I do. And it really doesn't matter which subset those particular instructions belong to. I'd even buy a new computer for that. Even better - that would be a perfect excuse for buying a new machine.

Comment: How do you compute your `__mmask64`? Can you already transpose them during generation? Otherwise, some simple advice: 1) use bitwise-or instead of addition 2) generate the upper and lower half separately to split the dependency chain.

Comment: Nevermind my suggestion 1) -- this is not supported for 64bit masks ...

Comment: @chtz  it's by `cmpgt_epu8`, and I cannot transpose them - at least not without additional computation that would exceed 8 cycles. 2) I'm already doing that way. - two vectors with 4bits filled each. I just streamlined them for this question. I thought there to be some "magic" instructions :-)

Comment: Can you efficiently get these masks together in the form of an `__m512i`? Just computing masks and moving them would *work* but I think just doing that already costs about as much as what you have. If you had the masks in that form, there would be a trick with a byte permute and an `vgf2p8affineqb` (at least I think so, I didn't work it out fully, and I think it's a waste of time to work it out if you cannot efficiently get the masks in that form in the first place)

Comment: @harold In fact, I do 16 `cmpgt_epu8` (16 surrounding pixels vs the center one) that can hardly be altered since those 16 "surrounding pixels" come from `alignr`.

Comment: @harold You already helped me out greatly by pointing out GFNI. I just wonder why Intel hid the GFNI subset in"other" category in their Intrinsics guide.

Comment: @harold: if OoO exec can hide the latency of a store-forwarding stall, 8x `kmov` stores of the masks to an `alignas(64)` array and a 64-byte vector reload could work.  That would take pressure off the ALU ports, and is ok for throughput - [What are the costs of failed store-to-load forwarding on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46135369) - an in-flight SF stall doesn't block successful store-forwarding or other stores.   Maybe with some software-pipelining or a 2-phase cache-blocked arrangement you could give the stores enough time to commit and avoid the SF stall.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: GFNI has legacy-SSE forms so they could implement it on their low-power CPUs that didn't support AVX2.  (To accelerate RAID6 in NAS boxes, for example.)  That makes it special, and not just an AVX512 extension.  Although with GFNI + AVX1 or AVX512, there are wide versions of it.  Intel's online intrinsics guide seems to mis-label the 128-bit versions as requiring AVX-512VL + GFNI, only using the `v` mnemonic.  https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/GF2P8AFFINEQB shows the existence of the legacy-SSE GF2P8AFFINEQB encoding.