# Setting/getting 1-bits of __m256i vector from integer array of bit positions

Tags: bit-manipulation, intrinsics, avx, avx2

**Setting bits:**

Given an array `int inds[N]`, where each `inds[i]` is a 1-bit position in `[0, 255]` range (and all `inds[i]` are sorted and unique), I need to set corresponding bits of `__m256i` to 1.

Is there a better way than what I do below:

```
alignas(32) uint64_t buf[4] = {0};

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    int ind = inds[i];
    buf[ind / 64] |= 1ul << (ind % 64);
}
auto r = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)buf);
```

**Getting bits:**

In the opposite operation, I need to compute product of double values at bit-1 positions. I.e., given `double const sizes[256]` compute product of some of them (at positions given by `__m256i` mask).

```
inline
double size (__m256i r, double const sizes[256])
{
    alignas(16) uint64_t buf[4];
    _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)buf, r);

    double s[4] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    // __builtin_ctzl(i) gives next position
    // and i &= i - 1 clears that bit

    for (; buf[0] != 0; buf[0] &= buf[0] - 1)
        s[0] *= sizes[__builtin_ctzl(buf[0]) + 0 * 64];

    for (; buf[1] != 0; buf[1] &= buf[1] - 1)
        s[1] *= sizes[__builtin_ctzl(buf[1]) + 1 * 64];

    for (; buf[2] != 0; buf[2] &= buf[2] - 1)
        s[2] *= sizes[__builtin_ctzl(buf[2]) + 2 * 64];

    for (; buf[3] != 0; buf[3] &= buf[3] - 1)
        s[3] *= sizes[__builtin_ctzl(buf[3]) + 3 * 64];

    return s[0] * s[1] * s[2] * s[3];
}
```

Same question: better way to do it?

Comment: There's nothing obvious using SIMD.  Use `uint32_t` or narrower for better ILP (bits in separate dword chunks can get set in parallel).  `uint16_t` chunks could be even better if there are a lot of bits set, if the compiler still makes efficient asm using `bts ax, cx` to modulo the count. Especially if `inds` is sorted so we load/store the same element repeatedly.  (See the links in my comment on [Sieve of Eratosthenes in x86 assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/548870) for discussion of optimal asm for setting a bit in a bit-array given an index.)

Comment: Is `inds[]` sorted and large (many bits set in the result)?  If so, perhaps use a nested loop that detects when to move to the next chunk, so each `uint64_t` chunk accumulates in a register, not reload/store for each bit-setting operation.

Comment: Yes, it's sorted.

Comment: If `inds[]` is short, only a few bits set, [set individual bit in AVX register (\_\_m256i), need "random access" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39475525) for each element and combining with `_mm256_or_si256` might be a win.  `vpbroadcastd` load / `vpsubd` / `vpsllvd` to materialize a vector with one bit set.  Actually that might be decent even for many bits set; I'd forgotten how cheap that was.  (Especially without spending a lot of effort getting the compiler to emit efficient scalar asm using `bts reg,reg` to do `dst |= 1ULL<<(src&63)` in one uop on Intel.)

Comment: Setting multiple bits in parallel would require routing indices to the correct SIMD element for that bit-number, which would require a reverse shuffle or something.

Comment: Your questions are only remotely related. I suggest to ask a new question for the second part.

Comment: (Partially contradicting my last comment): If you are able to use a list of indexes directly instead of first "compressing" it to a bitvector, the second problem would be trivial using `_mm256_i32gather_pd`.

Comment: The second problem can be solved with a sequence of 64 `vblendvpd`, `vmulpd`, `vpsllq`. Proof of concept: https://godbolt.org/z/ea3dsTMGb (with better unrolling of the multiplications, this might run in ~140 cycles -- the bottleneck is `vblendvpd` which requires `2p5` at least until Broadwell: https://uops.info/html-instr/VBLENDVPD_YMM_YMM_YMM_YMM.html).

Comment: With AVX-512, load the bitmap as masks and do merge-masking multiplies (starting with a vector of `1.0`), like `_mm256_mask_mul_pd`.  (Or `_mm512` if you want.)  And of course the usual horizontal reduction at the end, narrowing in half at each step.  ([Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764)).  Or as chtz says, gathers are good if you have an index-list, especially on Intel hardware (not as efficient on AMD).  If you don't have AVX-512, gathers are even more attractive since the alternative using masks is worse.

Comment: @chtz Between compression and decompression there are avx instructions on bit masks to compute the final mask that's used in size computation.
Compressions happen rarely, so not important to performance. bitmask manipulations mixed with size computations are the bulk of the computation.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with AVX512, and more efficient than the scalar approach in some cases, depending on N.

There is something else though, the scalar approach has a problem that can be fixed: a loop-carried dependency through memory. For example GCC compiles the code like this, (relevant part extracted)

```
.L3:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]
    mov     rdx, r8
    add     rdi, 1
    mov     rcx, rax
    shr     rax, 6
    sal     rdx, cl
    or      QWORD PTR [rsp-32+rax*8], rdx
    cmp     rsi, rdi
    jne     .L3
```

That `or` is loading/storing the same memory location in (most) successive loop iterations. This can be avoided by writing separate loops for each chunk of the result,

```
__m256i set_indexed_bits2(uint8_t* indexes, size_t N)
{
    alignas(32) uint64_t buf[4] = { 0 };
    if (N < 256)
        indexes[N] = 255;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (indexes[i] < 64)
        buf[0] |= 1ull << indexes[i++];
    while (indexes[i] < 128)
        buf[1] |= 1ull << indexes[i++];
    while (indexes[i] < 192)
        buf[2] |= 1ull << indexes[i++];
    while (i < N)
        buf[3] |= 1ull << indexes[i++];
    return _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)buf);
}
```

At the source level that looks like there is still a dependency through memory, but when it's written this way (where the index in the array is constant) compilers are likely to apply an optimization where they temporarily use a register for `buf[0]` and so on, for example here's an excerpt from what GCC made of that (which is fairly representative of what other compilers do too):

```
.L15:
    add     rax, 1
    mov     r11, rdi
    sal     r11, cl
    movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rdx+rax]
    or      rsi, r11
    cmp     cl, -65
    jbe     .L15
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-16], rsi
```

Much better (though GCC missed the opportunity to use `bts` with a register destination here, which is efficient unlike the version with a memory destination). In fact more than twice as good in my tests, but that will depend on `N` and other factors.

And here are the AVX512 hacks for good measure. On my PC (rocket lake), this is faster (in the sense of throughput being higher, I did not test latency) than the improved scalar code for some `N`, with Peter's suggestions now around 16 or more, not bad. Conversion to AVX2 seems possible, but that would make the threshold where it begins to be worth it higher.

```
__m512i indexes_to_bits64(__m512i indexes, __mmask64 valids)
{
    // make valid bytes in the range 0..63, make invalid bytes out-of-range
    indexes = _mm512_and_epi64(indexes, _mm512_set1_epi8(63));
    indexes = _mm512_mask_blend_epi8(valids, _mm512_set1_epi8(-1), indexes);
    __m512i one = _mm512_set1_epi64(1);
    __mmask64 m = 0x0101010101010101;
    __m512i b0 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_cvtepu8_epi64(_mm512_castsi512_si128(indexes)));
    __m512i b1 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_maskz_permutexvar_epi8(m, _mm512_setr_epi64(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), indexes));
    __m512i b2 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_maskz_permutexvar_epi8(m, _mm512_setr_epi64(16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), indexes));
    __m512i b3 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_maskz_permutexvar_epi8(m, _mm512_setr_epi64(24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31), indexes));
    indexes = _mm512_shuffle_i64x2(indexes, indexes, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 0, 3, 2));
    __m512i b4 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_cvtepu8_epi64(_mm512_castsi512_si128(indexes)));
    __m512i b5 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_maskz_permutexvar_epi8(m, _mm512_setr_epi64(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), indexes));
    __m512i b6 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_maskz_permutexvar_epi8(m, _mm512_setr_epi64(16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), indexes));
    __m512i b7 = _mm512_sllv_epi64(one, _mm512_maskz_permutexvar_epi8(m, _mm512_setr_epi64(24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31), indexes));
    __m512i b012 = _mm512_ternarylogic_epi64(b0, b1, b2, 0xFE);
    __m512i b345 = _mm512_ternarylogic_epi64(b3, b4, b5, 0xFE);
    __m512i b67 = _mm512_or_epi64(b6, b7);
    return _mm512_ternarylogic_epi64(b012, b345, b67, 0xFE);
}

__m256i set_indexed_bits_avx512(uint8_t* indexes, int N)
{
    // load values 0..63 into one chunk,
    // 64..127 in the next chunk
    // 128..191 in the third chunk
    // 192..255 in the last chunk
    // this automatically expanded based on bits 7 and 6
    __m512i chunk0 = _mm512_loadu_epi8(indexes);
    __mmask64 valids0 = _mm512_cmple_epu8_mask(chunk0, _mm512_set1_epi8(63));
    int chunk0_count = std::countr_one(valids0);
    valids0 = _bzhi_u64(valids0, N);
    __m512i chunk1 = _mm512_loadu_epi8(indexes + chunk0_count);
    __mmask64 valids1 = _mm512_cmple_epu8_mask(chunk1, _mm512_set1_epi8(127));
    int chunk1_count = std::countr_one(valids1);
    valids1 = _bzhi_u64(valids1, std::max(0, N - chunk0_count));
    __m512i chunk2 = _mm512_loadu_epi8(indexes + chunk0_count + chunk1_count);
    __mmask64 valids2 = _mm512_cmple_epu8_mask(chunk2, _mm512_set1_epi8(191));
    int chunk2_count = std::countr_one(valids2);
    valids2 = _bzhi_u64(valids2, std::max(0, N - chunk0_count - chunk1_count));
    __m512i chunk3 = _mm512_loadu_epi8(indexes + chunk0_count + chunk1_count + chunk2_count);
    __mmask64 valids3 = _bzhi_u64(-1ULL, std::max(0, N - chunk0_count - chunk1_count - chunk2_count));
    // 1 << bottom 6 bits
    chunk0 = indexes_to_bits64(chunk0, valids0);
    chunk1 = indexes_to_bits64(chunk1, valids1);
    chunk2 = indexes_to_bits64(chunk2, valids2);
    chunk3 = indexes_to_bits64(chunk3, valids3);
    // interleave and reduce horizontally
    __m512i chunk01 = _mm512_or_epi64(
        _mm512_unpacklo_epi64(chunk0, chunk1),
        _mm512_unpackhi_epi64(chunk0, chunk1));
    __m512i chunk23 = _mm512_or_epi64(
        _mm512_unpacklo_epi64(chunk2, chunk3),
        _mm512_unpackhi_epi64(chunk2, chunk3));
    __m256i chunk01_2 = _mm256_or_si256(_mm512_castsi512_si256(chunk01), _mm512_extracti64x4_epi64(chunk01, 1));
    __m256i chunk23_2 = _mm256_or_si256(_mm512_castsi512_si256(chunk23), _mm512_extracti64x4_epi64(chunk23, 1));
    __m128i chunk01_3 = _mm_or_si128(_mm256_castsi256_si128(chunk01_2), _mm256_extracti128_si256(chunk01_2, 1));
    __m128i chunk23_3 = _mm_or_si128(_mm256_castsi256_si128(chunk23_2), _mm256_extracti128_si256(chunk23_2, 1));
    return _mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(chunk01_3), chunk23_3, 1);
}
```

Comment: `sal     r11, cl` is 3 uops on Intel, 1 on AMD.  Hopefully if you compile with `-march=x86-64-v3` (AVX2+FMA + BMI1/2), compilers will use `shlx` (1 uop on Intel and AMD).  Obviously `bts` would still be better, especially on Intel (1 uop vs. 2 on AMD), so it's disappointing compilers are still bad at peephole optimization of `var |= 1ULL << (n&63)` into `bts`.

Comment: You could mask the counts before unpacking from epi8 to epi64, so you only need one `vpandq`.  Also, with some vector shuffle constants for Ice Lake `vpermb`, you could unpack the higher qwords with one shuffle each rather than `vpermq` + `vpmovzx`.  (Zero-masking for the `vpermb` can accomplish zero-extension without having any known-zero elements.)  Maybe a middle ground of 3 vector constants, so the shuffle work is `vpmovzxbq` + 3x `vpermb`, then `vextracti64x4` then repeat.  All the `vpermb` can use the same `k` mask = 0x0101010101010101, zeroing the high 7 bytes of each qword.

Comment: Nice idea to generate more than 1 bit per `sllv` though!  For very small N (or just competing with scalar?), looping over [set individual bit in AVX register (\_\_m256i), need "random access" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39475525) with 256-bit vectors could work.  (Maybe unrolled by 2 to accumulate with `vpternlogd` instead of `vpor` if AVX-512 or AVX10 is available.)

Comment: If it's rare to have more than half the bits set in any given chunk, could be worth branching on `chunk0_count` and so on to only do the low 32 indices of any given group.  When that's always sufficient, it could be nearly a 2x speedup.

Comment: To save on mask operations, use the 64-bit mask once while the counts are still bytes, to give non-selected elements an out-of-range shift count.  (SIMD shifts saturate the count, so e.g. a count of `0xFF` will shift the bit out.)  Perhaps a merge-masked AND with a vector of all-one bytes?  Or not, there's only epi32 and epi64 element size for `and`, so a separate blend I guess.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've put in some of the suggestions, at least I think that's more or less what you meant?

Comment: Very cool; sounds like close to a 4x speedup!  `_mm512_or_epi64(indexes, _mm512_movm_epi8(~valids));` could be a single uop `vpblendmb` (`_mm512_mask_blend_epi8`) with one of the out-of-range constants you already have, like `_mm512_set1_epi8(191)`.  Or I think the AND + BLEND could be replaced with a single merge-masking `vpermb`, merging into a `set1(191)` or `set1(-1)` vector. (That would require a `vmovdqa64` register copy, but if we're bound on overall vector execution ports, mov-elimination makes that free. IIRC, Ice Lake only disabled mov-elim for scalar. But it's a port5 only shuffle.)

Comment: @PeterCordes something is going wrong now, it has become slower than the original, maybe MSVC is pranking me somehow idk yet what's up

Comment: I tracked it down to MSVC doing a really dumb back-to-back spill and reload, poking the code in ways that shouldn't matter made that go away.. cool I guess

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Zen 4 runs `_mm512_extracti64x4_epi64` on any port (although still half throughput unfortunately), vs. `vshufi64x2` (`_mm512_shuffle_i64x2`) only on FP12 competing with `vpermb` and `vpmovzxbq`.  (`vpsllvq` runs on FP23, so only partial overlap with shuffles, and there's significant other work, so IDK if Zen 4 ends up bottlenecked on throughput of any individual port)