# Fast way to get a close power-of-2 number (floating-point)

Tags: c++, x86, floating-point, ieee-754

In numerical computation, it is often needed to scale numbers to be in safe range.

For example, computing Euclidean distance: `sqrt(a^2+b^2)`. Here, if magnitude of `a` or `b` is too small/large, then underflow/overflow can happen.

A common approach to solve this is to divide numbers by the largest magnitude number. However, this solution is:

- slow (division is slow)
- causes a little extra inaccuracy

So I thought that instead of dividing by the largest magnitude number, let's multiply it with a close power-of-2 reciprocal number. This seems a better solution, as:

- multiplication is much faster than division
- better accuracy, as multiplying with a power-of-2 number is exact

So, I'd like to create a small utility function, which has a logic like this (by `^`, I mean exponentiation):

```
void getScaler(double value, double &scaler, double &scalerReciprocal) {
    int e = <exponent of value>;
    if (e<-1022) { scaler=2^-1022; scalerReciprocal = 2^1022; }
    } else if (e>1022) { scaler=2^1022; scalerReciprocal = 2^-1022; }
    } else { scaler=2^e; scalerReciprocal = 2^(2046-e); }
}
```

This function should return a normalized `scaler` & `scalerReciprocal`, both are power-of-2 numbers, where `scaler` is near to `value`, and `scalerReciprocal` is the reciprocal of `scaler`.

The maximum allowed exponents for `scaler`/`scaleReciprocal` are `-1022..1022` (I don't want to work with subnormal `scaler`, as subnormal numbers can be slow).

What would be a **fast way** to do this? Can this be done with pure floating-point operations? Or should I extract the exponent from `value`, and use simple `if`s to do the logic? Is there some kind of trick to do the comparison with (-)1022 fast (as the range is symmetric)?

Note: `scaler` doesn't need to be the closest possible power-of-2. If some logic needs it, `scaler` can be some small power-of-2 away from the closest value.

Comment: I don't think it will answer your question but if you are looking for increasing performances the fastest way of multiplying and dividing by 2 is bit shifting. In signal processing you subtract the offset of the signal and as you said scale it so that range being [0,1] and you design the filter to have max magnitude 1. Plus I don't understand: you are scaling only if the exponent is smaller than -1022 or bigger than 1022: why is that? what range should it be?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: No, scaling would always happen. But `scaler` should only have exponents between `-1022..1022` (which is almost the whole range. Only the problematic border values are eliminated).

Comment: Are you interested in portable pure C that will compile efficiently for x86, or are you also interested in C with intrinsics for SIMD instructions like AVX512 `_mm512_getexp_pd` (extract exponent as a `double`) and  [`_mm512_scalef_pd`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=2403,6062,4147,4841,4841&techs=SSE2,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&text=_mm512_scalef_pd) which does `dst[63:0] := tmp_src1[63:0] * POW(2, FLOOR(tmp_src2[63:0]))` (i.e. adds the integer part of a double to the exponent field of another.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm mostly interested in pure C, or maybe extensions, which are widely available. AVX is still not that widespread. But thanks for mentioning it, I didn't know about `_mm512_getexp_pd`/`_mm512_scalef_pd`. They seem similar to the old `FXTRACT`/`FSCALE`.

Comment: In pure C, if you end up clamping anything, write it so it can efficiently compile to `minsd` / `maxsd` (or auto-vectorize with their SIMD versions).  Those are SSE2 and thus baseline for x86-64, and I think most SIMD instruction sets have packed min/max instructions.  See [What is the instruction that gives branchless FP min and max on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199125).  e.g. `a < b ? a : b`.  You can just separately clamp the scaler and its reciprocal.  Of course if you're doing integer exponent stuff, you may need to clamp in the integer range before stuffing into a `double`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yep, thanks for the info. I have a clamp, and then I need to create a double value based on the clamp. I'm expecting, that there could be some bit-trick here. If the clamp doesn't modify the value, then I need a simple `and` operation (just clear the significand). If the clamp modifies, then a little bit more happens. Maybe there is some extremely smart way to compact these `if`s to something clever.

Comment: Can you assume that C++ `double` is represented by IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: There's a standard predefined macro to tell you if it is or not.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: yes.

Comment: @PeterCordes With respect to the ternary operator and `minsd`, `minpd`, `maxsd`, `maxpd`, somehow clang does a better job than gcc. [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/OIyhCM)

Comment: It occurs to me another solution is to use an extreme version of the Veltkamp-Dekker split: `double get_scale(double x) { double d = x * (0x1p52 + 1); double t = d - x; return d - t; }`. That is just three ordinary arithmetic instructions, but it does not handle values near the upper end of the finite range.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: it's a nice trick to get a close power-of-2 value. On platforms where manipulating floating point numbers as integers is slow, this trick can be a part of the solution. I need clamped exponents (can be easily done with comparison), and the reciprocal as well (I don't see any fast way to have this without manipulating the value as integer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on wim's answer, here's another solution, which can be faster, as it has one less instruction. The output is a little bit different, but still fulfills the requirements.

The idea is to use bit operations to fix border cases: put a `01` to the lsb of the exponent, no matter of its value. So, exponent:

- 0    becomes 1    (-1023 becomes -1022)
- 2046 becomes 2045 (1023 becomes 1022)
- other exponents modified as well, but just slightly: the number can become two times larger compared to wim's solution (when exponent lsb changes from `00` to `01`), or halved (when 10->01) or 1/4 (when 11->01)

So, this modified routine works (and I think that it's pretty cool that the problem can be solved with only [2 fast asm instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/r8BuNH)):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<immintrin.h>
/* gcc -Wall -m64 -O3 -march=sandybridge dbl_scale.c */

union dbl_int64{
    double d;
    uint64_t i;
};

double get_scale(double t){
    union dbl_int64 x;
    uint64_t and_i;
    uint64_t or_i;
         /* 0xFEDCBA9876543210 */
    and_i = 0x7FD0000000000000ull;
    or_i =  0x0010000000000000ull;
    x.d = t;
    x.i = (x.i & and_i)|or_i;                     /* Set fraction bits to zero, take absolute value */
    return x.d;
}

double get_scale_x86(double t){
    __m128d x = _mm_set_sd(t);
    __m128d x_and = _mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_set1_epi64x(0x7FD0000000000000ull));
    __m128d x_or  = _mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_set1_epi64x(0x0010000000000000ull));
            x     = _mm_and_pd(x, x_and);
            x     = _mm_or_pd(x, x_or);
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(x);
}

/* Compute the inverse 1/t of a double t with all zero fraction bits     */
/* and exponent between the limits of function get_scale                 */
/* A single integer subtraction is much less expensive than a            */
/* floating point division.                                               */
double inv_of_scale(double t){
    union dbl_int64 x;
                     /* 0xFEDCBA9876543210 */
    uint64_t inv_mask = 0x7FE0000000000000ull;
    x.d = t;
    x.i = inv_mask - x.i;
    return x.d;
}

double inv_of_scale_x86(double t){
    __m128i inv_mask = _mm_set1_epi64x(0x7FE0000000000000ull);
    __m128d x        = _mm_set_sd(t);
    __m128i x_i      = _mm_sub_epi64(inv_mask, _mm_castpd_si128(x));
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_castsi128_pd(x_i));
}


int main(){
    int n = 14;
    int i;
    /* Several example values, 4.94e-324 is the smallest subnormal */
    double y[14] = { 4.94e-324, 1.1e-320,  1.1e-300,  1.1e-5,  0.7,  1.7,  123.1, 1.1e300,  
                     1.79e308, -1.1e-320,    -0.7, -1.7, -123.1,  -1.1e307};
    double z, s, u;

    printf("Portable code:\n");
    printf("             x       pow_of_2        inverse       pow2*inv      x*inverse \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){  
        z = y[i];
        s = get_scale(z);
        u = inv_of_scale(s);
        printf("%14e %14e %14e %14e %14e\n", z, s, u, s*u, z*u);
    }

    printf("\nx86 specific SSE code:\n");
    printf("             x       pow_of_2        inverse       pow2*inv      x*inverse \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){  
        z = y[i];
        s = get_scale_x86(z);
        u = inv_of_scale_x86(s);
        printf("%14e %14e %14e %14e %14e\n", z, s, u, s*u, z*u);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which 3 instructions are you counting?  Yours reduces it to 2, just ANDPS / ORPS instead of ANDPS/MINPD/MAXPD.  Or if you're counting actually scaling 2 values according to the max magnitude, then you'd need AND + AND + (select the highest exponent with MAXPD or AVX512 VPMAXUQ) + OR + PSUBQ, and then apply it to both inputs with 2x MULPD or VFMADD... if you or the compiler can contract the first step after normalization into an FMA.

Comment: And BTW, avoid intrinsics for scalar; they suck because there's no way to tell the compiler you want a vector with an undefined upper element, i.e. no scalar->128 equivalent of `__m256 _mm256_castps128_ps256 (__m128 a)`.  Unfortunately, other than clang most compilers do actually waste an instruction zero-extending for `_mm_set_sd(t)`. [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39318496).  Just use the union type-pun version, I think all the major x86 compilers su

Comment: Oh, I just looked at your Godbolt link.  That's weird that for scalar compilers fail to use `ANDPS` / `ORPS`, even in a loop, and actually extract to GP regs with `movq`.  There are no call-preserved XMM registers in x86-64 System V, so they couldn't hoist the constants, but using them from memory would still be a win.  Hopefully compilers will auto-vectorize the pure C version, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yep, it's actually just two :) I was happy that I could shave off one instruction from wim's version, I didn't bothered to check that actually the first instruction is not really needed. Thanks for the link, I'll check it!

Comment: You might want to add a version of your function that takes 2 inputs and returns a scale factor to use for both, because like I said you can combine that max-magnitude finding with zeroing the significand.

Comment: Nice solution. I think your `get_scale` function is a bit more wobbly than mine, nevertheless, it may work well for your application.

Comment: @wim: Remember the OP's use-case is just to scale values to a magnitude where squaring them won't overflow to infinity or underflow to denormal/zero, for stuff like `sqrt(a^2+b^2)` and similar.  Leaving the larger one in the `[1..2)` range instead of `[0.5 .. 1)` is totally fine.  Using `OR` to apply a minimum is a really nice idea for that use-case.

Comment: @PeterCordes: With the AND/OR idea, normal values are scaled to the [0.5...8.0) range, which is perfect for reliably computing a hypotenuse, indeed.

Answer (score 7):

Function `s = get_scale(z)` computes the "close power of 2". Since the fraction bits of `s`
are zero, the inverse of `s` is just an (inexpensive) integer subtraction: see function `inv_of_scale`.

On x86 `get_scale` and `inv_of_scale` compile to quite efficient assembly with clang. 
Compiler clang translates the ternary operators to `minsd` and `maxsd`, 
see also Peter Cordes' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297525/fast-way-to-get-a-close-power-of-2-number-floating-point#comment95417093_54297525).
With gcc, it is slightly more efficient to 
translate these functions to x86 intrinsics 
code (`get_scale_x86` and `inv_of_scale_x86`), [see Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/mRGU2w).

Note that [*C explicitly permits type-punning 
through a union, whereas C++ (c++11) has no such permission*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11996970)
Although gcc 8.2 and clang 7.0 do not complain about the union, you can improve
the C++ portabily by [using the `memcpy` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17789928) instead of the 
union trick. Such a modification of the code should be trivial.
The code should handle subnormals correctly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<immintrin.h>
/* gcc -Wall -m64 -O3 -march=sandybridge dbl_scale.c */

union dbl_int64{
    double d;
    uint64_t i;
};

double get_scale(double t){
    union dbl_int64 x;
    union dbl_int64 x_min;
    union dbl_int64 x_max;
    uint64_t mask_i;
           /* 0xFEDCBA9876543210 */
    x_min.i = 0x0010000000000000ull;
    x_max.i = 0x7FD0000000000000ull;
    mask_i =  0x7FF0000000000000ull;
    x.d = t;
    x.i = x.i & mask_i;                    /* Set fraction bits to zero, take absolute value */
    x.d = (x.d < x_min.d) ? x_min.d : x.d; /* If subnormal: set exponent to 1                */
    x.d = (x.d > x_max.d) ? x_max.d : x.d; /* If exponent is very large: set exponent to 7FD, otherwise the inverse is a subnormal */
    return x.d;
}

double get_scale_x86(double t){
    __m128d x = _mm_set_sd(t);
    __m128d x_min = _mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_set1_epi64x(0x0010000000000000ull));
    __m128d x_max = _mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_set1_epi64x(0x7FD0000000000000ull));
    __m128d mask  = _mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_set1_epi64x(0x7FF0000000000000ull));
            x     = _mm_and_pd(x, mask);
            x     = _mm_max_sd(x, x_min);
            x     = _mm_min_sd(x, x_max);
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(x);
}

/* Compute the inverse 1/t of a double t with all zero fraction bits     */
/* and exponent between the limits of function get_scale                 */
/* A single integer subtraction is much less expensive than a            */
/* floating point division.                                               */
double inv_of_scale(double t){
    union dbl_int64 x;
                     /* 0xFEDCBA9876543210 */
    uint64_t inv_mask = 0x7FE0000000000000ull;
    x.d = t;
    x.i = inv_mask - x.i;
    return x.d;
}

double inv_of_scale_x86(double t){
    __m128i inv_mask = _mm_set1_epi64x(0x7FE0000000000000ull);
    __m128d x        = _mm_set_sd(t);
    __m128i x_i      = _mm_sub_epi64(inv_mask, _mm_castpd_si128(x));
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_castsi128_pd(x_i));
}


int main(){
    int n = 14;
    int i;
    /* Several example values, 4.94e-324 is the smallest subnormal */
    double y[14] = { 4.94e-324, 1.1e-320,  1.1e-300,  1.1e-5,  0.7,  1.7,  123.1, 1.1e300,  
                     1.79e308, -1.1e-320,    -0.7, -1.7, -123.1,  -1.1e307};
    double z, s, u;

    printf("Portable code:\n");
    printf("             x       pow_of_2        inverse       pow2*inv      x*inverse \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){  
        z = y[i];
        s = get_scale(z);
        u = inv_of_scale(s);
        printf("%14e %14e %14e %14e %14e\n", z, s, u, s*u, z*u);
    }

    printf("\nx86 specific SSE code:\n");
    printf("             x       pow_of_2        inverse       pow2*inv      x*inverse \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){  
        z = y[i];
        s = get_scale_x86(z);
        u = inv_of_scale_x86(s);
        printf("%14e %14e %14e %14e %14e\n", z, s, u, s*u, z*u);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks fine:

```
Portable code:
             x       pow_of_2        inverse       pow2*inv      x*inverse 
 4.940656e-324  2.225074e-308  4.494233e+307   1.000000e+00   2.220446e-16
 1.099790e-320  2.225074e-308  4.494233e+307   1.000000e+00   4.942713e-13
 1.100000e-300  7.466109e-301  1.339386e+300   1.000000e+00   1.473324e+00
  1.100000e-05   7.629395e-06   1.310720e+05   1.000000e+00   1.441792e+00
  7.000000e-01   5.000000e-01   2.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.400000e+00
  1.700000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.700000e+00
  1.231000e+02   6.400000e+01   1.562500e-02   1.000000e+00   1.923437e+00
 1.100000e+300  6.696929e+299  1.493222e-300   1.000000e+00   1.642544e+00
 1.790000e+308  4.494233e+307  2.225074e-308   1.000000e+00   3.982882e+00
-1.099790e-320  2.225074e-308  4.494233e+307   1.000000e+00  -4.942713e-13
 -7.000000e-01   5.000000e-01   2.000000e+00   1.000000e+00  -1.400000e+00
 -1.700000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00  -1.700000e+00
 -1.231000e+02   6.400000e+01   1.562500e-02   1.000000e+00  -1.923437e+00
-1.100000e+307  5.617791e+306  1.780059e-307   1.000000e+00  -1.958065e+00

x86 specific SSE code:
             x       pow_of_2        inverse       pow2*inv      x*inverse 
 4.940656e-324  2.225074e-308  4.494233e+307   1.000000e+00   2.220446e-16
 1.099790e-320  2.225074e-308  4.494233e+307   1.000000e+00   4.942713e-13
 1.100000e-300  7.466109e-301  1.339386e+300   1.000000e+00   1.473324e+00
  1.100000e-05   7.629395e-06   1.310720e+05   1.000000e+00   1.441792e+00
  7.000000e-01   5.000000e-01   2.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.400000e+00
  1.700000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.700000e+00
  1.231000e+02   6.400000e+01   1.562500e-02   1.000000e+00   1.923437e+00
 1.100000e+300  6.696929e+299  1.493222e-300   1.000000e+00   1.642544e+00
 1.790000e+308  4.494233e+307  2.225074e-308   1.000000e+00   3.982882e+00
-1.099790e-320  2.225074e-308  4.494233e+307   1.000000e+00  -4.942713e-13
 -7.000000e-01   5.000000e-01   2.000000e+00   1.000000e+00  -1.400000e+00
 -1.700000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00  -1.700000e+00
 -1.231000e+02   6.400000e+01   1.562500e-02   1.000000e+00  -1.923437e+00
-1.100000e+307  5.617791e+306  1.780059e-307   1.000000e+00  -1.958065e+00
```

---

**Vectorization**

Function `get_scale` should vectorize with compilers that support auto-vectorization. The following piece of 
code [vectorizes very well with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/OIyhCM) (no need to write SSE/AVX intrinsics code).

```
/* Test how well get_scale vectorizes: */
void get_scale_vec(double * __restrict__ t, double * __restrict__ x){
    int n = 1024;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x[i] = get_scale(t[i]);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately gcc doesn't find the `vmaxpd` and `vminpd` instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Based on your solution, I've found a (perhaps) faster one.

Comment: Re: union type-punning: GNU C++ explicitly supports it as an extension to ISO C++.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html.  I think MSVC also supports it, but IDK if it's documented.  Still, no downside to using `memcpy` for good compilers, as long as it's the full width of the type.

Comment: @PeterCordes: as far as I know, MSVC doesn't utilize optimization based on strict aliasing rules. For example, [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/70DBWw) reloads `*a` twice unnecessarily.

Comment: @geza: strict aliasing is related but separate from union type-punning.  `*(int*)&my_float` is still UB in GNU C, although it may often work in practice for simple cases like this where there aren't also FP operations mixed in.

Comment: @PeterCordes: sure :) I meant, that with MSVC, all kind of type-punning works, not just union based, like with gcc/clang. I've never seen documented this anywhere though, it's just based on my experience.

Comment: @geza: I see.  Yes, I think it's true that MSVC intentionally supports pointer-casting for type punning as well (because lots of legacy non-portable code uses it).  In general we have to be carefully about looking at a missed optimization / happens-to-work and concluding it's officially-supported, but I think in this case we can.  (Based on widespread usage of the idiom, and that if MSVC was ever going to break something, it would probably break that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Re: union type-punning: Thanks for the links. I did a few experiments with `union` vs. `memcpy`. With clang, MSVC, and gcc, I couldn't find any difference between the assembly generated for these two cases. With icc there was a small diffeence

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
double frexp (double x, int* exp);
```

Returned value is the fractional part of of x and exp is the exponent (minus the offset).

Alternatively, the following code gets the exponent part of a double.

```
int get_exp(double *d) {
  long long *l = (long long *) d;
  return ((*l & (0x7ffLL << 52) )>> 52)-1023 ;
}
```

Comment: `frexp` does more than needed here. And does less, as I need to clamp exp, and then I need to convert back to get a `double`. I don't think that `frexp` really usable in my case, as I need speed. I'd rather extract the exponent by hand, if that's the way to go (it's just a `memcpy`, shift and a mask).

Comment: @geza: `frexp` is just a shift and a mask, standardized and documented to make it portable.  If you want to adjust the exponent, pair it with `ldexp` (note that `ldexp` adds to the exponent rather than replacing it)

Comment: @BenVoigt: unfortunately, no. Check out the source code. It handles nan/inf, and subnormal numbers. And it does some logic, which could be part of my `if (exp<-1022) ..` logic. So with `frexp`, I'd have redundant code. I'm not saying that it is very slow. But still, it is better (for me) to extract exponent manually, if that's the way to go.