# Cast from double to __m128

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, inline-assembly, intrinsics

I was looking for a way to cast a double to a _m128 to take advantage of the intrinsic instructions.

I tried using:

```
double d = 7654321.1234567;
_m128 ret =  *reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(d);
```

But of course I got the message:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘double’ to type ‘__m128* {aka __vector(4) float*}’
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, inline-assembly solution is fine~

Comment: `__m128 ret =  *reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(d);` -> `__m128 ret =  *reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(&d);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you actually wanted a vector of `double` (`__m128d`), you're looking for **`_mm_set_sd(d)` to zero-extend a double into `__m128d` like `_mm_set_pd(0, d)`.**

See [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE2,SSE3,AVX2,AVX_512&expand=5655,257,5657,5607,5607,4023,557,0,4933&text=(double).  I found this one by searching on `(double` to find intrinsics that take a `double` (or `double*`) arg.

`__m128` is a vector of 4 `float`; did you want double -> float conversion into the low element of a vector?  Like `_mm_set_ps(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, d);`

---

You don't want to point a `__m128d*` at a scalar double because the vector is twice as wide as a `double`.  If anything would have made sense, it would be `(__m128d)d` or a static or reinterpret_cast version of that.

But there's unfortunately no way to just cast a double to a `__m128d` with an undefined upper element, AFAIK, even though scalar float / double and `__m128d` naturally live in XMM registers.  See [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496/how-to-merge-a-scalar-into-a-vector-without-the-compiler-wasting-an-instruction)

Some compilers (well probably still just clang) can optimize away the zero-extension or broadcast into a `__m128d` vector if you only use scalar intrinsics and then extract a scalar result.  Other compilers actually waste instructions on the upper elements.